# How to get all ubuntu flavors

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu

since I'm not sure which Ubuntu Flavor to get I was wondering if there's any way I can get all installed at once (Ubunutu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu), and if so, will my performance decrease?
I've seen that some people can change flavors from their login screen, how can I do so?

PS.: I have a laptop 1.6 Ghz and 2GB of Ram, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You could quad-boot if you wanted which would not take any additional resources outside disk space as only one instance is running. I would just do Live-CD or LIve-USB to try out and see which you like better. Most of the difference is going to be in the window managers.

Comment: I would myself install them in virtual containers. Easy to set up. Easy to delete.

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

While Lubuntu, Xubuntu, etc exist as packages in the repos, installing them can sometimes break other desktop environments. For example I used to have problems with nautilus (from gnome) randomly drawing the desktop even after I installed Xubuntu, so I wouldn't recommend it. It would be better to try out different flavors from live cds.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to try the [Ubuntu AIO DVD](http://linuxaio.net/downloads/linux-aio-ubuntu/). This DVD contains every major Ubuntu flavor.

> We bring you some of the major Linux distributions (Ubuntu and
>   flavors, [...]) with different desktop
>   environments on one ISO file that can be burnt on one DVD / DVD DL or
>   USB 4GB+/8GB+ flash drive. Every one of them can be used as Live
>   system, with no need of installation on hard drive, or can be
>   eventually installed on computer for full system experience. - [LinuxAIO](http://linuxaio.net/)

---

Burn this ISO to a live DVD/USB and you will be able to test each flavor without having to install them on your computer.

When you have made your choice, simply install the flavor using this same DVD/USB. This way you won't have to install all necessary packages needed for each flavor (which might clutter your system. You only keep what you need.